# Python AttributeError object has no attribute when attribute defined in class

Tags: python, attributes, kivy, attributeerror

I am writing a utility platform at work using Kivy for my coworkers to use at the reception desk.  I am having trouble assigning a user to the session. Here is my code:

masterControl.py

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MasterControl(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MasterControl, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        m_currentUser = None

    def loginUser(self, emp):
        self.m_currentUser = emp
        print "I made it to login!"
        # remove login widget, add the rest of the UI according to the security level of the use
```

login.py

```
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from coreAPI.mastercontrol import MasterControl
from employee import Employee, getEmployees

class LoginWidget(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def loginBtnHandle(instance):
            empList = getEmployees()
            for emp in empList:
                if emp.m_aNum == uNameInput.text:
                    if emp.authenticate(pWordInput.text):
                        self.parent.loginUser(emp) # Here is where I get  AttributeError: 'MasterControl' object has no attribute 'loginUser'

        box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', size = (300, 110), size_hint = (None, None), spacing = 10)

        uNameInput = TextInput(hint_text = 'Username', 
                multiline = False, 
                size = (300, 30), 
                size_hint = (None, None), 
                cursor_color = [0,0,0,1], 
                write_tab = False)

        pWordInput = TextInput(hint_text = 'Password', 
                multiline = False, 
                size = (300, 30), 
                size_hint = (None, None), 
                cursor_color = [0,0,0,1], 
                password = True, 
                write_tab = False)

        loginBtn = Button(text = 'Login', size = (300, 50), size_hint = (None, None))
        loginBtn.bind(on_press = loginBtnHandle)
        loginBtn.bind(on_enter = loginBtnHandle)

        box.add_widget(uNameInput)
        box.add_widget(pWordInput)
        box.add_widget(loginBtn)

        self.add_widget(box)
```

employee.py

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
import pickle
import os

class Employee():
    def __init__(self, name, aNumber, password, clearance):
        self.m_name = name
        self.m_aNum = aNumber
        self.m_pWordHash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password) # Only store the password hash.  NEVER the password text
        self.m_clearance = clearance

    def authenticate(self, attempt):
        return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(attempt, self.m_pWordHash)

    def serialize(self):
        filename = 'users/' + self.m_aNum + '.emp'
        frozen = pickle.dumps(self)
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(frozen)
        f.close()
        return frozen

def getEmployees():
    empList = []
    path = 'users/'
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        f = open(path + filename, 'r')
        contents = f.read()
        empList.append(pickle.loads(contents))
    return empList

tempEmp = Employee('Tester', 'A12345678', 'password', 'HIGH')
tempEmp.serialize()
```

After the user is authenticated, the login widget calls mastercontrol's `loginUser` method.  When it does this, Python throws `AttributeError: 'MasterControl' object has no attribute 'loginUser'`.  As far as I have been able to tell, It should be able to call `loginUser`.  Ive been through the indentation, and have ruled out errors de-serialization of the employee objects as the cause.

Comment: You could publish a [mcve], I do not see any connection between MasterControl and LoginWidget, probably created another MasterControl.

Comment: In your `MasterControl` init method change `m_currentUser = None` to `self.m_currentUser = None`

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The `AttributeError: 'MasterControl' object has no attribute 'loginUser'` was due to the class MasterControl was not instantiated.

## Solutions

There are two solutions. The first solution assumed that MasterControl is the root widget.The second solution assumed that LoginWidget is the root widget.  Please refer to the snippets and output for details.

### Solution 1 - masterControl.py

1. Add *from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty*.
2. Add *from login import LoginWidget*
3. Define *m_currentUser* as an *ObjectProperty* and initialized it to *None*.
4. Add *LoginWidget* to *MasterControl*.

#### Snippets

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from login import LoginWidget


class MasterControl(BoxLayout):
    m_currentUser = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MasterControl, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(LoginWidget())
```

### Solution 1 - login.py

1. Remove/Comment off *from coreAPI.mastercontrol import MasterControl*.

### Solution 2 - login.py

1. Add *from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty*.
2. Define an *ObjectProperty* e.g. *masterControl*.
3. Instantie the *class MasterControl* and hook it up to the new ObjectProperty, *masterControl*.
4. Replace *self.parent.loginUser(emp)* with *self.masterControl.loginUser(emp)*

#### Snippets

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class LoginWidget(AnchorLayout):
    masterControl = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.masterControl = MasterControl()

        def loginBtnHandle(instance):
            empList = getEmployees()
            for emp in empList:
                if emp.m_aNum == uNameInput.text:
                    if emp.authenticate(pWordInput.text):
                        self.masterControl.loginUser(emp)
```

### Solution 2 - masterControl.py

1. Add *from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty*.
2. Define *m_currentUser* as an *ObjectProperty* and initialized it to *None*.

#### Snippets

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MasterControl(BoxLayout):
    m_currentUser = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MasterControl, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def loginUser(self, emp):
        self.m_currentUser = emp
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Called MasterControl.loginUser Successfully]